# Configure associated domain from .xcconfig

Tags: ios, associated-domains

I have an app with multiple schemes, where I want to have a different associated domain for each scheme.

I have the following `.entitlements` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:$(ASSOCIATED_DOMAIN)</string>
        <string>webcredentials:(ASSOCIATED_DOMAIN)</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My `.xcconfig` files look like this (`?mode=developer` is only there to verify everything is working and will be removed):

```
// ...
ASSOCIATED_DOMAIN="my.domain.com?mode=developer"
```

I tried to verify my link with the following command, but this opens mobile Safari:

```sh
xcrun simctl openurl booted 'https://my.domain.com/app/link'
```

---

My `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` file is accessible and when I inline my domain and remove the `$(ASSOCIATED_DOMAIN)` the app link works as expected by opening the app instead of Safari. In this case, my `.entitlements` file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:my.domain.com?mode=developer</string>
        <string>webcredentials:my.domain.com?mode=developer</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Does anybody have a suggestion what might be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a variable for the ASSOCIATED_DOMAIN value, consider specifying a separate entitlements file for each of the schemes.
In the relevant xcconfig file, this can be done by setting:

```
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = [location of the file].entitlements
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems that the entitlements files don't support variables. Instead of setting `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS` in the `.xcconfig` files, I've done it via the build settings in Xcode.

Comment: @MartinFink how did you solve the problem via build settings?

Comment: In the Build Settings screen, Filter for "Code Signing Entitlements"